# Is this function an open mapping?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Consider the cylindrical coordinate transformation:$$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, f(r,\theta,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z).$$ Then we can show that $U:=(0,\infty)\times(0,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R}$ is the largest connected open set such that $f|_U$ is one-to-one.

Define$$g:U\to f(U), g(r,\theta,z)=f(r,\theta,z).$$Is $g$ an open mapping?

Comment: $g$ is a homeomorphism, hence an open mapping.

Comment: Right; write down the inverse $g^{-1}$ and show that it is continuous. The only annoyance is dealing with the transitions between quadrants of the $xy$ plane.

Comment: @copper.hat I see that. I think I was trying to show whether f is an open mapping. But thank you for considering the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ is a bijection and its inverse on $f(U) = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(x,y,z) : y = 0, x > 0\}$ is

$$g^{-1} = \begin{cases}\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \arccos \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, z\right) & y \geq 0\\
\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, 2\pi - \arccos \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, z\right) & y < 0,
\end{cases}$$
which is obviously continuous when $y\neq 0$. Moreover
$$\lim_{\textbf{q}\to(x,0,z)} g^{-1}(\textbf{q}) = (-x,\pi,z),$$
so $g^{-1}$ is continuous and $g$ is an open map.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I think this gives me some idea to show whether f is an oppen mapping.